# Loaded records is not up to date. Using Hibernate and OpenSessionInViewFilter

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

I am using OpenSessionInViewFilter, Spring, and Hibernate for data access. When I commit a data record, my view results do not show the commited record using lazy loading.  My session factory configuration looks like this:

```
<bean id="dbcpDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dbcpDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dbcpDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>or.pac.Address</value>
            <value>or.pac.Customer</value>
            <value>or.pac.Documents</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">4</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean> 
   <bean id="locator" class="cc.SessionLocator">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

**OpenSessionInViewFilter** configuration in the web.xml looks exactly like this:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
        <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

**To obtain a session for my DAO** I have below SessionLocator class which opens session for me;

```
public class SessionLocator{

public static final ThreadLocal session = new ThreadLocal();
private static SessionLocator me;

static {
    try {
        me = new SessionLocator();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private SessionLocator() throws HibernateException, JDBCException {
}

public static Session currentSession() throws Exception {
    Session s = (Session) session.get();
    if (s != null) {
        s.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REFRESH);
    }

    if (s == null) {
        synchronized SessionLocator{
            s =openSession();
        }
        session.set(s);
    }

    return s;
}



public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    PersistenceManager.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public static Session openSession() {
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(sessionFactory, true);
    return session;
}

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

}

And then in **My DAO service** I do Save and Update like this:

```
    public boolean upsert(Object d) {
    try {
        SessionLocator.currentSession().saveOrUpdate(d);
                } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I call `upsert()`, I can see the record on the table, but the updated value does not show up in my view during lazy loading. Do any one knows why the hibernate cache is not refreshed with the current record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by removing below line from openSessionInViewFilter config:

```
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
```

And annotate the DAO Service with @Transactional annotation

```
@Transactional
public boolean upsert(Object d) {
try {
    SessionLocator.currentSession().saveOrUpdate(d);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
   }
   return true;
   }
```