# getting java.io.EOFException when trying to insert data in mysql from spring mvc app

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to submit data from spring mvc app to mysql . sometime i get the following error

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: StatementCallback; SQL [insert into networkwithusdb(company,firstname,lastname,email,address1,address2,city,state,zipcode,currentemployer,currentjobtitle,primarycareerarea,secondarycareerarea) values('HCA North Texas','dd','af','bhanukiran@imomentous.info','','','','KS','','','','Facilities','Facilities')]; Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.io.EOFException

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1963)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2874)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1623)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1715)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3243)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1343)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1260)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:508)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:395)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:518)
    at com.imomentous.hcanorthtexas.service.DatabaseService.insertNetworkData(DatabaseService.java:58)
    at com.imomentous.hcanorthtexas.controller.NetworkWithUsController.processNetworkWithUSForm(NetworkWithUsController.java:62)
    [... snip ...]    

** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

only few times i get this exception.

following are my configuration file:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${database.driver}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${database.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${database.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${database.password}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="3" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 5 FROM DUAL" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />

</bean>
```

and i am using the properties as:

```
database.driver =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XXXmobiledb
database.username=XXXX
database.password=XXXX
```

---

i am using:mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar
mysql server 5 .

sometimes database connection works properly and i get the result.

but sometimes it generates the error.
what might be the problem? If any have some idea please tell..thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that MySQL will disconnect the opened socket after a given time. You are advised to use a connection pool (such as c3p0).

See this post on the MySQL forum - http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,143312,180718#msg-180718. This should resolve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

It might happen after a long time of inactivity add validation Query to your dataSource bean:

```
<property name="validationQuery">
<value>Select 1</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `MySQL` from disconnecting your session after a given idle time, you can use *Spring* `OpenSessionInViewFilter` or *Interceptor* to handle session.

This will require additional session filter settings in your `web.xml` file. You can *mimic* [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302983/loaded-records-is-not-up-to-date-using-hibernate-and-opensessioninviewfilter).